# Fit image inside div height but center horizontal content while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

### Question

What should I edit to make the image be centered horizontally while fitting within the height of the containing `<figure>`?

The thumbnail will be 75px x 75px. Images uploaded may vary but will usually be approximately a 4:3 ratio, like 800px x 600px.

---

### HTML

```
<figure>
    <img src="">
</figure>
```

### Sass

```
figure {
    background-color: #777;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    img {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 5;
        height: 75px;
        width: auto !important;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this could help http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Answer (score 2):

### Ideal Approach

The best way to do this and have good cross browser support is using a `background-image` instead of an actual image tag. Check out this codepen:

https://codepen.io/treyhakanson/pen/eGVVpr

Basically, using `background-size: contain` will cause the image to be bound by its largest dimension, while maintaining its aspect ratio, and `background-position: center` will center the image within its container.

### Alternate Approach

If you cannot use `background-image` and must use `img` tags, check out the `object-fit` and `object-position` properties, which act similar to `background-size` and `background-position`, but for `img` and even `video` tags. It has [good cross browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit), but not as good as the aforementioned method. examples of this have been added to the codepen link.

Comment: I completely agree with you as far as what should be done. I was just wondering though how to accomplish similar look in the specific scenario.

Comment: I just added how to do it with standard image tags and `object-fit`/`object-position`, which have very [good support](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit), but not as good as the approach mentioned initially. Will update answer shortly.